# How to implement my own XBRL convertor?

Tags: java, xml, xbrl

I want to develop a XBRL converter which can convert documents/reports from .doc/.xml/.txt/.csv to a standard XBRL format. I have tried to search about it but could only get information from the perspective of business in which already developed software use is proposed, but I want something which can guide me build the application on my own. So I need any resource/help about the architecture of the converter/ tagging process. I want to implement the application in JAVA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed a XBRL converter to create an instance from an Excel sheet. I used VBA and some common components. The converter is compatible with the statutory reportings from the Dutch Taxonomy. It includes a discovery of the taxonomy and the creation of a hypercube. The Excel spreadsheet with the basic version is published on my website. The code is not 
protected. Also an explanation is there. It is in Dutch, so you should use something like Google translate. Perhaps this is gettng you started.

This is the link: http://www.dexbrlsite.nl/wiki/index.php/MSXML_oplossing

Regards, Jacques